# What are the list of method which I can in define in interface extended CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Every example with Spring Data JPA contains this method:

```
   public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

        List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

    }
```

Is there some other method which can JPA+Hibernate implement in runtime then findByVarialbleName and I can defined it here in repository ?

Comment: Nope, every example with JPA does NOT include that. The JPA API has no such XXXRepository. That is Spring Data JPA API, != JPA API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [query method document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods) 
Some example query method:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);

  // Enables the distinct flag for the query
  List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
  List<Person> findPeopleDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling ignoring case for an individual property
  List<Person> findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);
  // Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties
  List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling static ORDER BY for a query
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastname);
}
```

Spring Data JPA also supports `deleteBy`, `count`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but I think what you're driving at is `Query Methods`. There are some default methods supported (findAll, save, etc.) but you create the query from the actual method name itself, while using reserved keywords for more complex queries. Let's say your `Person` class also has an `int age` variable. You could then create a query method as follows: `Person findByLastNameAndAge(String lastName, int age)`. Here, `And` is a keyword, but there are many others you can use. Check out the documentation, there are many examples.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions